# Play multiple audio tracks sequentially, not simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the `<audio>` tag, and I want to have as many tracks playing as I add. But now they play at the same time, can I somehow make them play sequentially?

```
<audio id="audio1" preload="" autoplay="" loop="" type="audio/mp3" src="music/mus1.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="audio2" preload="" autoplay="" loop="" type="audio/mp3" src="music/mus.mp3"></audio>

<div id="pp" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="pVid();"><img src="img/heart.png"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function pVid() {
var audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
var audio2 = document.getElementById("audio2");

    audio1.paused ? audio1.play() : audio1.pause();
    audio2.paused ? audio2.play() : audio2.pause();
}
</script>
```

I found one solution, it works but not the way I want

```
var sounds = new Array(new Audio("music/mus1.mp3"), new Audio("music/mus.mp3"));
var i = -1;
pVid();

function pVid() {
    i++;
    if (i == sounds.length) return;
    sounds[i].addEventListener('ended', pVid);
    sounds[i].play();
}
```

Here everything just plays right away, but I want to be able to play the tracks myself through the button and pause at any time. This is done in the first version, but there all the tracks play at the same time

Comment: Couldn't you just do it with Promises or async await?

Comment: @F.Müller I'm not very good at javascript, so I'm looking for help

Comment: Will come up with something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [audio events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#events) as much as possible. We can use [freesound.org](https://freesound.org/) for testing.

```js
let sounds = new Array(new Audio("https://freesound.org/data/previews/46/46992_514283-lq.mp3"),
  new Audio("https://freesound.org/data/previews/610/610823_13156161-lq.mp3"),
  new Audio("https://freesound.org/data/previews/92/92005_1499847-lq.mp3"), new Audio("https://freesound.org/data/previews/46/46992_514283-lq.mp3"),
  new Audio("https://freesound.org/data/previews/610/610823_13156161-lq.mp3"),
  new Audio("https://freesound.org/data/previews/92/92005_1499847-lq.mp3"));

let current = random(0);
let paused = true;

// set event handlers on all audio objects
for (let s of sounds) {
  s.addEventListener('ended', ended);
  s.addEventListener('play', play);
  s.addEventListener('pause', pause);
}

updateVolume()

// handle button click
function playPause() {
  if (paused) {
    sounds[current].play();
    btn.innerText = 'pause';
    paused = false;

  } else {
    sounds[current].pause();
    btn.innerText = 'play';
    paused = true;
  }
}

function ended(e) {
  document.getElementById(current + '').classList.remove('playing');
  document.getElementById(current + '').classList.remove('paused');
  /*i++;
  if (i >= sounds.length) //loop
    i = 0;
  */
  current = random(current); // shuffle

  paused = true;
  playPause();
}

function play() {
  document.getElementById(current + '').classList.add('playing');
  document.getElementById(current + '').classList.remove('paused');
}

function pause() {
  document.getElementById(current + '').classList.add('paused');
  document.getElementById(current + '').classList.remove('playing');
}

function random(i) {
  let next = i;
  while (next == i)
    next = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
  return next;
}

function updateVolume() {
  for (let s of sounds) {
    s.volume = volume.value;
  }
}
```

```css
#list {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
}

#controls {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 1rem;
  width: 50px;
}

#volume {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  transform-origin: 75px 75px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(50%);
}

.playing {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.paused {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<Button id=btn onClick='playPause()'>play</Button>
<div id=list>
  <div id='0'>Guitar</div>
  <div id='1'>Drum</div>
  <div id='2'>Violin</div>
  <div id='3'>Guitar</div>
  <div id='4'>Drum</div>
  <div id='5'>Violin</div>
</div>
<div id=controls>
  <label for="volume">Volume</label><br>
  <input id=volume type="range" id="volume" name="volume" min="0" max="1" step='.1' value='.5' onInput='updateVolume()'>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I need)) and is it difficult to make this mini-player so that the tracks switch randomly?

Comment: It's easy. In `ended()` function instead of incrementing the index assign random number to it. See the updated answer.

Comment: cool, thanks a lot, you are the best)) and the last question, is it possible to somehow adjust the sound? and it plays really loud

Comment: I've updated the answer. Refer [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

## Audio files

For testing, I used a few free sound-effects audio files from https://www.freesoundeffects.com.

To make it work in all browsers it is recommended by w3c to use the `<audio>`-tag with `<source>` tags.

## Solution

I added some arbitrary sound files and buttons. The buttons will reset all the audios that are currently playing then play the sounds in the `data-track` attributes.

### data-track syntax:

```
track-a                   // will play track a
track-a;track-b           // will play track a followed by track b
track-a+track-b           // will play track a and b simultaniously
track-a+track-b;track-c   // as above but add track c to the end
```

You could do something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    audio {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <script defer type="application/javascript">
    let activeTimeout;

    function init(player) {
      player.innerHTML = `play ${player.dataset.label}`;
      player.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    }

    function reset(audio) {
      clearTimeout(activeTimeout);
      audio.pause();
      audio.currentTime = 0;
    }

    function dequeue(tracks) {
      console.log("Queue:", tracks);
      if (tracks.length >= 1) {
        const track = tracks.pop();
        const multiTrack = track.split('+');
        let maxDuration = 0;
        multiTrack.forEach((it) => {
          const audio = document.querySelector(`[data-audio="${it}"]`);
          maxDuration = Math.max(maxDuration, audio.duration);
          audio.play();
        });
        activeTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          dequeue(tracks);
        }, maxDuration * 1000);
      }
    }

    function clickHandler(e) {
      const allAudios = document.querySelectorAll('[data-audio]');
      const trackAttr = this.dataset.track;
      const tracks = trackAttr.split(';');
      if (tracks) {
        allAudios.forEach(reset);
        dequeue(tracks.reverse()); // reverse to make the pop-operations faster
      } else {
        console.log('No track defined!');
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      const players = document.querySelectorAll('[data-player]');
      players.forEach((it) => init(it));
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <audio data-audio="applause" controls="controls" preload="preload">
          <source src="https://www.freesoundeffects.com/files/mp3_426807.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></source><!-- replace with your audio file -->
        </audio>
  <audio data-audio="bark" controls="controls" preload="preload">
          <source src="https://www.freesoundeffects.com/files/mp3_89478.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></source><!-- replace with your audio file -->
        </audio>
  <audio data-audio="chirp" controls="controls" preload="preload">
          <source src="https://www.freesoundeffects.com/files/mp3_89489.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></source><!-- replace with your audio file -->
        </audio>

  <button data-player data-label="bark!" data-track="bark" />
  <button data-player data-label="chirp!" data-track="chirp" />
  <button data-player data-label="applause!" data-track="applause" />
  <button data-player data-label="applause then bark!" data-track="applause;bark" />
  <button data-player data-label="bark then chirp then bark again!" data-track="bark;chirp;bark" />
  <button data-player data-label="applause then chirp!" data-track="applause;chirp" />
  <button data-player data-label="applause with chirp then bark!" data-track="applause+chirp;bark" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why no one mentioned the onended event

```
<audio id="aud1" onended="playaud2()" src="whatever.mp3"> <!--first audio-->
<audio id="aud2" src="whatever.mp3"> <!--second audio-->
<script>
//the onended event calls a function when the audio finishes playing
function playaud2() {
document.getElementById("aud2").play()}
</script>
```

As simple :)

Comment: But chaining onended is not that straightforward. It will work in a very simple scenario.  If you initialize the audio stuff dynamically it gets tricky. Imagine if you want to play only the audio1 and not always along with audio2 (provide both options). This forces tight coupling.

Comment: @F.Müller You are correct. But, ch11 did say that he's not good. So I thought maybe something easier wouldn't confuse him/her. Obviously, he/she can at her/his convenience add additions. But at a basic level, I think this does fine 
PS. please feel free to upvote if you think this works at a basic level!

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can check if you have an element with a simple truthy/falsy check:

```js
if (!slider) return;
```

Comment: What is `slider`?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones undefined ;)

Comment: `slider` was how the object was referred to in the title, but someone edited that out